# How to stop Atom automatically putting imports to the top in python

Tags: python, atom-editor

I have this code in atom;

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "D02C6E9F82CB9F4D"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///site.db"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from flaskSite import routes
```

When I save this in atom it puts the `from flaskSite import routes` to the top but I need at the bottom. 
Why does it do this?

These are the packages installed to atom;

1. atom-live-server
2. autoclave-html
3. autocomplete-python
4. emmet
5. file-icons
6. kite
7. script
8. python-autopep8

Thank you

Comment: It's probably the `autopep8` if I were to guess. Why does your `import` *need to be at the bottom*?

Comment: If `flaskSite.routes` is relying on a global instance of `app` (which is what I'm guessing based on the concern for positional `import`), you may want to reconsider the design of your application, or that module at least

Comment: Thanks it was autopep8

Answer (score 0):

It's for sure the autopep feature, got the same problem and have to disable that package each time I don't want to rearrange the imports.